# EntityNotFoundException when using @Cacheable

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, redis

On my application I have multiple entities like:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@ToString(of = {"id", "code", "nameContentType", "observations"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "room")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "desk")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Desk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "name")
    private byte[] name;

    @Column(name = "name_content_type")
    private String nameContentType;

    @Column(name = "observations")
    private String observations;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Coordinates coordinates;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "desk")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Reservation> reservations = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "desks", allowSetters = true)
    private Room room;

  
}
```

All relationships represented with a collection are cached with `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`.

When I delete some records of related Entities I get:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.**.domain.Reservation with id ***
```

I don't know if I have to make any extra adjustments to my cache settings or how to debug the problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you updated Hibernate to the latest version 5.4.32.Final? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.